# clientY undefined scroll by

Tags: javascript, scroll

Hello J wanted make a scroll on click to a p tag. But i read that not every browser supported the version with "smooth" at the end. So I tried to make it with a timeout and for loop. I also compared this with mouse position. when i do it in console.log it works. but when i use return not.

```
let angebot = document.getElementById("bieten");
let beispiel = document.getElementById("beispiel");

document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
angebot.addEventListener("click", angebotscroll);

function move(event) {
  let position = event.clientY;
  return position;
}

document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
angebot.addEventListener("click", angebotscroll);

setTimeout(function() {
  for (let i = 0; move() < beispiel.offsetTop; i++) {
    window.scrollBy(0, i);
  }
}, 10);
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientY' of undefined
    at move (navigation.js:35)
    at navigation.js:44

Comment: You call the function `move` and not pass the `event` parameter. of course it's undefined

Answer (score 0):

You call the function `move` in the setTimeout, and not pass the `event` parameter. of course it's undefined.

You should make variable `position` in the global scope. update it in the function `move` (which called **only** from the listener), and in the `setTimeout` get the variable `position` instead calling the function `move`